# build 2d array in java using recrursion by giving a positive number

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array

i have a program that build 2d array by giving a positive number and it display the result in a recursion way like this example:

n = 6 ...where n is the positive nbumber

the result will display this 2d array:

0

1 0

2 1 0

3 2 1 0

4 3 2 1 0

5 4 3 2 1 0

can anyone help me to get this result ??

this is my code that i start with :

```
public class positiveNumber{

 public static void main(String[] args){

   for(int i = 0 i<= 6 i++){
   {
    for(int j = 0 j <= 6 j++){

      if(i == j){

     {

    }

   }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Adding numbers them in **list** and print the list on each iteration in reverse order

```
public class positiveNumber{

 public static void main(String[] args){
      int n= taking Input from user;
      List<Integer> listOfNumbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for(int i = 0 ; i< n ; i++){
          listOfNumbers.add(i);
          printListInReverse(listOfNumbers);
   }
}
public static void printListInReverse(List<Integer>listOfNumbers){
       List temp = new ArrayList(listOfNumbers);
       Collections.reverse(temp);
       System.out.println(temp); //either iterate the list or print in once
}
}
```

**Output**

```
[0]
[1, 0]
[2, 1, 0]
[3, 2, 1, 0]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

if you want to remove these **[]** brackets then instead of printing the list directly use Iterator to iterater the list and then print each element in list

**Update**

Same Program with **recursion**

---

```
public class positiveNumber{
    static List<Integer> listOfNumbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static int n;

     public static void main(String[] args){
           n= "take input fmo user"
           print(0);
    }
    /*
     *Using Recursion
     */
    public static void print(int i){
              if(i==n)
                 return;
              listOfNumbers.add(i);
              printListInReverse();
              print(i+1);
        }

    public static void printListInReverse(){
           List temp = new ArrayList(listOfNumbers);
           Collections.reverse(temp);
           System.out.println(temp); //either iterate the list or print in once
    }
    }
```

Comment: that is the result that i want but i thought that i might need to use the recursion way  or 2 for loops

Comment: Check out the updated program for recursion

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[][] numbers = new int[6][6];
    displayPyramid(6, numbers);
    System.out.println("2d array is");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers[i]));
}

private static void displayPyramid(int next, int[][] numbers) {
    if (next == 0) {
        return;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = numbers[0].length - next, k = 0; i >= 0; i--) {
        numbers[numbers[0].length - next][k++] = i;
        sb.append(i);
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
    displayPyramid(next - 1, numbers);
}

Output:  
0 
1 0 
2 1 0 
3 2 1 0 
4 3 2 1 0 
5 4 3 2 1 0 
2d array is
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```